# Problemas al utilizar Datatables

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, datatable

Buen día, estoy realizando un proyecto personal y realmente soy nuevo en esto, queria usar el plugin de datatable pero se presento un problema en mi código ya que al tratar de usar Data tables  no me funcionan y me muestra los siguientes errores en pantalla no se si es por la versión de jquery o simplemente no estoy implementando de manera correcta la datatable:
Aqui el error

```
 jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.25/datatables.min.js:119:137)
    at Function.each (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:3003)
    at S.fn.init.each (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:1481)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.25/datatables.min.js:119:90)
    at Function.each (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:3003)
    at S.fn.init.each (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:1481)
    at S.fn.init.u [as dataTable] (https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.25/datatables.min.js:112:13)
    at S.fn.init.k.fn.DataTable (https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.25/datatables.min.js:196:292)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/personal/Vista/Ingresos/ingreso_principal.php?id_ingreso=44:156:20)
    at e (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:30038) undefined
S.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (datatables.min.js:119)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (datatables.min.js:119)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.u [as dataTable] (datatables.min.js:112)
    at S.fn.init.k.fn.DataTable (datatables.min.js:196)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (ingreso_principal.php?id_ingreso=44:156)
    at e (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
```

Este es el código:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashoboard</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css_vista/estilo_dashboard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css_vista/estilo_3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fontello.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css_vista/actualizar_estilo.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.25/datatables.min.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.25/datatables.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="btn-menu">
                <label for="btn-menu" class="icon-menu"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Tu cartera</h1>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
    <div class="container-menu">
        <div class="cont-menu">
            <nav>
                <a href="../Vista/inicio.html">Inicio</a>
                <button type="button" id="">Ingresos</button>
                <a href="#">Actualizar información</a>
                <a href="#">Soporte</a>
            </nav>
            <label for="btn-menu" class="icon-cancel"></label> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    include("../../controlador/conectar.php");
    // mostrar datos
    $ingresos = "SELECT id_ingreso,nombre_ingreso,valor_ingreso,Descripcion_ingreso,fecha_ingreso FROM ingresos";
    // Hacer suma de los ingresos
    $SUM="SELECT SUM(valor_ingreso) FROM ingresos";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $SUM);
            $TotalSuma=$resultado->fetch_assoc();
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mostrar datos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table_container"  id="table_container">
        <button id="mostrar_agregar">Añadir</button>
    <table class="display tabla" id="tabla_id">
        <thead>
            <tr class="edit_table"> 
                <th>Nombre del ingreso</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Descripción del ingreso</th>
                <th>Fecha del ingreso</th>
                <th colspan="2">Acciones</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>         
            <?php
              $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$ingresos);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){?>
            <tr  class="edit_table_2">
                <td><?php echo $row["nombre_ingreso"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["valor_ingreso"]; ?></td>
                <td  class="descri"><?php echo $row["Descripcion_ingreso"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["fecha_ingreso"]; ?></td>
                <td >
                    <a class="links" id="actualizar_ingreso" href="ingreso_principal.php?id_ingreso=<?php echo $row["id_ingreso"] ?>">Editar</a>
                    <a class="links_2" id="eliminar_ingresos" href="../../controlador/ingresos/eliminar.php?id_ingreso=<?php echo $row["id_ingreso"] ?>">Eliminar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
         } mysqli_free_result($resultado);  
        ?>
        <td class="filaSuma" colspan="5">Total ingresos:  <?php 
            foreach ($TotalSuma as $total) {
             echo $total, "\n";
            }
         ?></td>
         </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Formulario_modal_agregar_ingreso -->
    <nav  class="formulario_agregar" id="formulario_agregar">
        <form  action="../../controlador\ingresos\mostrar_ingreso.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" class="contact" id="contact" name="formulario">
            <br>
            <div class="form__ingreso" id="grupo__nombre" >
                <label for="nombre_ingreso" class="form__label">Nombre ingreso</label>
                <div class="form__grupo-input">
                    <input maxlength="30" type="text" class="form__input" name="nombre_ingreso" id="nombre_ingreso">
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form__ingreso" id="grupo__valor" >
                <label for="valor_ingreso" class="form__label">Valor ingreso</label>
                <div class="form__grupo-input">
                    <input  maxlength="10" type="text" class="form__input" name="valor_ingreso" id="valor_ingreso">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form__ingreso" id="grupo__descripcion" >
                <label for="Descripcion_ingreso" class="form__label">Descripcion ingreso</label>
                <div class="form__grupo-input">
                    <input type="text" class="form__input" name="Descripcion_ingreso" id="Descripcion_ingreso">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form__ingreso" id="grupo__fecha" >
                <label for="fecha_ingreso" class="form__label">Fecha ingreso</label>
                <div class="form__grupo-input">
                    <input type="date" class="form__input" name="fecha_ingreso" id="fecha_ingreso">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form__grupo-btn">
                    <input type="submit" name="enviar" class="actualizar">
                    <input type="button" value="Cerrar" id="cerrar_agregar">
            </div>
            </form>

    </nav>
    <!-- Modal actualizar ingreso -->
    <?php 
        if (isset($_GET["id_ingreso"])) {
        $id_ingreso = $_GET["id_ingreso"];
        $ingresos_actualizar  = "SELECT * FROM ingresos WHERE id_ingreso='$id_ingreso'";    
     ?>
    <div class="container_update" id="container_update">
    <form action="../../controlador/ingresos/procesar_actualizacion.php" method="post"  class="update" id="update">
            <?php
              $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$ingresos_actualizar);
            while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){?>
                <br>
                <input type="hidden"  name="id_ingreso" value="<?php echo $fila["id_ingreso"]; ?>">
                <label for="nombre_ingreso">Nombre del ingreso</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text"  name="nombre_ingreso" value="<?php echo $fila["nombre_ingreso"]; ?>">
                <br>
                <label for="valor_ingreso">Valor</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" required="" name="valor_ingreso" value="<?php echo $fila["valor_ingreso"]; ?>">
                <br>
                <label for="Descripcion_ingreso">Descripción del ingreso</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" maxlength="80"  required="" name="Descripcion_ingreso" value="<?php echo $fila["Descripcion_ingreso"]; ?>">
                <br>
                <label for="fecha_ingreso">Fecha del ingreso</label>
                <br>
                <input type="date" name="fecha_ingreso"  required="" value="<?php echo $fila["fecha_ingreso"]; ?>">
                <br>
        <?php
         } mysqli_free_result($resultado);
        ?>
        <div class="form__grupo-btn">
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Actualizar" class="actualizar">
        <input type="button" value="Cerrar" id="cerrar_actualizar">
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
     <?php 
        }
      ?>
    <script src="../js/confirmar_eliminar.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/mostrar.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#tabla_id').DataTable();
} );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ya trate de diversas formas pero la verdad no he podido dar solución al problema a pesar de que ya he buscado posibles soluciones en foros y vídeos, muchas gracias

Comment: en mi trabajo no puedo ver la imagen, que error te da?

Comment: PD: Recuerdo que `Datatables js` da problemas si usas `thead` y `tbody`, intenta con `<tr>` directo

Comment: Ya agregue el error como parte del codigo para poder visualizarlo

Comment: Una consulta, te muestra los resultados?, modifique tu código y lo enlace a una base en mi equipo y me muestra resultados, claro si verifico datatable sigue indicando que hay errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error da cuando el numero de columnas del thead, no es igual al tbody.

```
<?php
         } mysqli_free_result($resultado);  
        ?>
        <td class="filaSuma" colspan="5">Total ingresos:  <?php 
            foreach ($TotalSuma as $total) {
             echo $total, "\n";
            }
         ?></td>
```

En este trozo de codigo esta insertando un columna, sin añadir una nueva fila, cambialo por el siguiente:

```
<?php
         } mysqli_free_result($resultado);  
        ?>
        <tr><td class="filaSuma" colspan="5">Total ingresos:  <?php 
            foreach ($TotalSuma as $total) {
             echo $total, "\n";
            }
         ?></td></tr>
```

espero te sirva!!

o intenta con esto, ya que no estoy seguro que dataTable funcione con colspan.

```
<?php
         } mysqli_free_result($resultado);  
        ?>
        <tr><td class="filaSuma" colspan="5">Total ingresos:  <?php 
            foreach ($TotalSuma as $total) {
             echo $total, "\n";
            }
         ?></td>
<td style="display: none;"></td>
<td style="display: none;"></td>
<td style="display: none;"></td>
<td style="display: none;"></td></tr>
```

Con este codigo, estamos añadiendo la misma cantidad de columnas del thead, pero las ocultamos con style="display: none;"

Comment: Ya probe tu comentario pero aun me muestra errores, no se si tengas otra opción ,Muchas gracias

Comment: Trata de eliminar ese trozo de código y me cuentas, no se si datatable funcione con la propiedad colspan.

Comment: añadi, otro codigo en la respuesta, para que pruebes con ese.

Comment: Ya pude arreglar siguiendo tus consejos muchas gracias

Comment: @SERGIODANIELAYALAORTIZ, si la respuesta te sirvió, no olvides marcarla como aceptada.